# How to open multiple photos in Preview App with NSWorkspace

Tags: macos, nsworkspace

```
let photos = [NSURL(string: "/photo1.png")!, NSURL(string: "/photo2.png")!]

NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURLs(photos, withAppBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Preview", options: NSWorkspaceLaunchOptions.Default, additionalEventParamDescriptor: nil, launchIdentifiers: nil)
```

I tried the code above. It returns true and opens the preview app but not with photos. Single item in array didn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably your photos cannot be found. Are u sure u placed them into root directory "/" ?

Comment: @MarekH its not there but I can open them with `openFile` so the url's seem correct

Comment: Try to pass it as array of key NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments (configuration)

Comment: @MarekH could you show an example? I tried but couldn't make the syntax work. And do I post the folder as a URL and images as arguments?

Comment: This works in terminal "open -a Preview.app 1.jpg 1.png" so you can provide argv arguments to Preview.app I think google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a long time ago, but I recently needed to do the same thing and got it working by using full paths to the image files.

```swift
// get application url from bundle ID
guard let previewUrl = NSWorkspace.shared.urlForApplication(withBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Preview")
else { return }

// paths to image files
let urls = [
    URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/myuser/path/to/image1.jpg"),
    URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/myuser/path/to/image2.jpg")
]

// launch configuration
let config = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
config.addsToRecentItems = false
config.createsNewApplicationInstance = true
config.allowsRunningApplicationSubstitution = false
config.activates = true

// launch Preview.app
NSWorkspace.shared.open(urls, withApplicationAt: previewUrl, configuration: config) { app, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("unable to launch Preview.app: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    if let app = app {
        print("launched Preview.app with pid \(app.processIdentifier)")
    }
}
```